# Issue with Java 8 Lambda for effective final while incrementing counts

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, final

I want to use Java 8 Lambda expression in following scenario but I am getting *Local variable fooCount defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final*. I understand what the error message says, but I need to calculate percentage here so need to increment `fooCount` and `barCount` then calculate percentage. So what's the way to achieve it:

```
        // key is a String with values like "FOO;SomethinElse" and value is Long
        final Map<String, Long> map = null;
    ....
    private int calculateFooPercentage() {
        long fooCount = 0L;
        long barCount = 0L;

        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (k.contains("FOO")) {
                fooCount++;
            } else {
                barCount++;
            }
        });

        final int fooPercentage = 0;
        //Rest of the logic to calculate percentage
        ....
        return fooPercentage;
    }
```

One option I have is to use `AtomicLong` here instead of `long` but I would like to avoid it, so later if possible I want to use parallel stream here.

Comment: Maybe you should be using [`stream.count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count--)

Comment: If you could do this, you would get race conditions with parallel streams unless you used `AtomicLong`. Ideally, you'd use a more functional style like in khelwood's answer, which will work fine with parallel streams

Comment: A simple solution is to not make the variables local. If you make them members of the class then you can happily update them in a lambda expression. However, as the answers have noted, this won't work in a parallel stream unless you make the variables atomic or use another synchronisation mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count--) method in stream to do counts for you.

```
long fooCount = map.keySet().stream().filter(k -> k.contains("FOO")).count();
long barCount = map.size() - fooCount;
```

If you want parallelisation, change [`.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) to [`.parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--).

Alternatively, if you were trying to increment a variable manually, and use stream parallelisation, then you would want to use something like `AtomicLong` for thread safety. A simple variable, even if the compiler allowed it, would not be thread-safe.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Could you please show how to use parallelization here, in a thread safe way?

Comment: @Learner Yes, I've added that into my answer.

Answer (score 6):

To get both numbers, matching and non-matching elements, you can use

```
Map<Boolean, Long> result = map.keySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(k -> k.contains("FOO"), Collectors.counting()));
long fooCount = result.get(true);
long barCount = result.get(false);
```

But since your source is a `Map`, which knows its total size, and want to calculate a percentage, for which `barCount` is not needed, this specific task can be solved as

```
private int calculateFooPercentage() {
    return (int)(map.keySet().stream().filter(k -> k.contains("FOO")).count()
                 *100/map.size());
}
```

Both variants are thread safe, i.e. changing `stream()` to `parallelStream()` will perform the operation in parallel, however, it’s unlikely that this operation will benefit from parallel processing. You would need humongous key strings or maps to get a benefit…

Comment: Nice answer, Brevity at its best :)

Comment: @Holger, thanks for your answer. I also need to use the `long` value in the percentage calculation. So essentially I want the sum of all the _values_ where _key_ contains `"FOO"` instead of just the `count()`

Comment: Here is what I changed it to:
`return (int)(map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("SLD")).mapToLong(e -> e.getValue().longValue()).sum() * 100 / map.size());`

Comment: Explicit unboxing should not be necessary, i.e. `.mapToLong(e -> e.getValue())` should be sufficient. This can also be written using a method reference `.mapToLong(Map.Entry::getValue)`. However, the ratio between the sum and the map size (i.e. count) isn’t a percentage. You would actually need to calculate `long total=map.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();` followed by `/*yourcode*/ *100/total`

Comment: Thanks @Holger for providing the details.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers indicating you should use `count`or `partitioningBy`.

Just to explain the atomicity problem with an example, consider the following code:

```
private static AtomicInteger i1 = new AtomicInteger(0);
private static int i2 = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(0, 100000).parallel().forEach(n -> i1.incrementAndGet());
    System.out.println(i1);

    IntStream.range(0, 100000).parallel().forEach(n -> i2++);
    System.out.println(i2);
}
```

This returns the expected result of 100000 for `i1` but an indeterminate number less than that (between 50000 and 80000 in my test runs) for `i2`. The reason should be pretty obvious.